# Retrieve cookie values in ASHX 

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, ashx

It's there a way to retrieve cookie value in ASHX Handler ?

I set a cookie in a page, and I want to retrieve it in my ashx. My cookie is always null.

I save my cookie like this

```
HttpCookie tokenCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
 tokenCookie.Values["siteGuid"] = authenticationInfo.SiteGuid.ToString();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(tokenCookie);
```

I retrieve my cookie like this

```
 HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
 return new Guid(cookie["siteGuid"]);
```

***Ok sorry that was my fault. My handler was on a sub domain.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access the cookies across the sub-domain. You might need to assign the domain name for the cookies>

```
Response.Cookies["domain"].Domain = ".somedomain.com";
```

***Don't miss the .(Dot) before the domain name.***

Answer (score 5):

You can access the cookies collection on the Request object.

It would look something like the following

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a cookie:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add("UserName");
```

Read a cookie:

```
var cookie = (HttpCookie)HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserName"];
```